# GAE: dev_appserver.py too few arguments

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've tried to run the following command:

```
C:/slimapp>dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

but returns the result

```
too few arguments
```

how to fix this or how to run it correctly

I am trying to test a slim application in my pc before deployment in google app engine

Comment: Try `dev_appserver.py -h` or `dev_appserver.py --help` (or just `dev_appserver.py`?) to see what's expecting (it *should* be enough, at least one linux, also try to check which `dev_appserver.py` is it actually executing, in case you have some other one somehow in the path). Can you show your `app.yaml` file?

Comment: this is my app yaml

Comment: Please edit your post and place the content there, formatted as code, it's unreadable in comments. Thanks.

Comment: this is the pastebin link of app.yaml

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1LV16ADM